# How to import python file without mentioning it's parent folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

So basically i have the following structure in my project:

app
|____conf
|              |________ config.py
|         |________ **init**.py
|
|____scripts
             |________ "lots of scripts".py

And what i want is to be able to import "config.py" (from the scripts folder) without having to mention the parent folder "conf" (from conf import config)

I have added the path of the conf folder into my PYTHONPATH variable but it only allows me to import by using:

"from conf import config"  which is i guess the expected behaviour

It works when i run my code from pycharm remote, but on the shell it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a file named sitecustomize.py inside the site-packages folder of my python installation, that gets executed before python runs.

the file contains a simple sys.path.append() of my conf folder.